# Programming on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, programming, source-code

To begin with I'm a new Linux user, my distro is "Ubuntu GNOME 15.04" if that matters.

I would like to start writing code on Linux, I have to install editors, compilers, IDE etc just like windows or is there any other preferred way?

If you can even provide me with a link-tutorial it would be really helpful, cause no matter how I google it I couldn't find anything...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Up to you, there are many IDE to use in software center, take a look, I like to just use Gedit, it is simple and has syntax highlighting, compiler is installed, it is g++, easy too use, open terminal and type `g++ /path/to/files/to/compile` easy. Thats all you need, IDE is personal preference so try some, there free, here is g++ docs http://homepages.gac.edu/~mc38/2001J/documentation/g++.html If you are an experienced programmer, you will be up and running in seconds

Comment: I'm not that experienced, I'm a junior and IT student at the moment... Until today I used programs like DevC++ and CodeBlocks in order to develop my coding skills and gain some experience with some languages..

Gedit and the way it works looks pretty intresting, does every IDE works like Gedit? I just have to type the path in terminal and it will execute the problem if the proper packs are installed?

Comment: Gedit is just a text editor, not an IDE, it is pre installed, I use just that and a terminal for programming in C++, If you used code-blocks before it is also available for Ubuntu, check software center, works just like the windows version. You said `? I just have to type the path in terminal and it will execute the problem if the proper packs are installed?` do you mean when compiling ? You need nothing for that (well maybe this `sudo apt-get install build-essentials` ), just type `gcc ` and feed it your files, it will compile them and tell you and problems in the code.

Comment: Ah, cool!!
I mean compile and run, the only editor that I used in the past was Notepad++. So when I need to run my code, I have to copy it.. Is there any way to also run it through terminal, or I can only compile it...

PS: Sorry if my questions are pretty dumb

Comment: When you compile with gcc it will give you a file you can run (.out for c++) What is the language you want to learn ? I guess you could compile and run in one command like this `gcc  /path/to/source /more/source/if/you/have/them && /path/to/a.out` this would (in c++ atleast) compile the source and the immediately run the resulting file (a.out)

Comment: I get it, so after compiling I will get a new file which will be the executable!! great!!
I'm trying to learn Python at the moment, but I will also keep working on my C/C++ abilities!

Comment: That is good for c++, you don't have to compile `python` as it is a scripting language, just call it whatever.py and run from a terminal, thats it, no compilation needed. Also python has it's own (sort of IDE) right in the linux terminal,  just run `python` in terminal and start codeing.

Comment: Yeap, I know the basics about `python`! But I didn't know that it has some kind of IDE right in the terminal, thanks a lot!! You are really friendly and helped a lot!!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with `gcc` (GNU C) compiler, but the rest is up to you. You can install an IDE like `geany`. Personally I got through my C programming class with `nano` text editor and gcc.

Other languages will  require installation, for instance Java. The `openjdk` is open source version for that and available for installation with `apt-get` or from software center.

As for Python and Perl, I want to say they come by default, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Python 2 is definitely preinstalled, not sure about Python 3.

Comment: I've already installed geany, but it's just an editor if I'm not mistaken..

Do I have to install something extra in order to run a program?

I'm pretty sure from what I've read in other posts that you are right about Python at least, it comes by deafault.